# Fetching value from dataframe with certain condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe which is containing 3 columns (`['A','B','C]`) and 3 rows in it.
We are using a for loop to fetch value(storing into variable)  from above dataframe based upon certain condition from column B.
Further we are using list to store value present in variable.
Here question is upon checking list value, we are getting variable value, its type.
I'm not sure why it is happening. As list should contain only variable value only.

Please can anyone help us to get ideal solution for same.

Thanks,
Bhuwan

```
dataframe: columns-A,B,C rows value- a to i :df = ([a,b,c][d,b,f][g,b,i]).
list_1=[]
for i in range(0,9):
    variable_1=df['A'][df.B == 'b']
    list_1.append(variable_1)
print(list_1):
```

Ideal output: `['a','d','g']`
while we are getting output as 
`['a type: object','d type: object','g type: object']`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your ideal output like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'd', 'g'], 'B': ['b', 'b', 'b'], 'C': ['c', 'f', 'i']})

list_1 = list(df[df['B'] == 'b']['A'].values)  # <- this line

print(list_1)
> ['a', 'd', 'g']
```

You just need:
1) to filter your dataframe by column "B" `df[df['B'] == 'b']`
2) and only then take values of the resulted column "A", turning them into list